# form post not being sent to form action php page

Tags: php

My form doesn't seem to be sending values to the form action page. I am trying to set them to variable and all the variables echo as undefined. I used var_dump($_POST); and it says all the values in the array are null. I have looked at my form. I have tested the code online as well as on wamp and xampp with the same results. If someone could please help me I would it would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on this for a week now.
This is my form page hash.php:

```
<html>
 <body>
 <h2>Modal Signup Form</h2>

 <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" 
style="width:auto;">Sign Up</button>

 <div id="id01" class="modal">
 <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

 <form action="action.php" class="modal-content"  method= "post">
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
  <hr>
  <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Check Availability" name="username" required>

  <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

  <label for="phone"><b>Phone</b></label>
  <input type="tel" minlength="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter 10 digit Phone number" name="phone">

  <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label> <span id = 'message'> </span>
  <input type="password" pattern= "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])(A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{12,}" placeholder="Enter Password" id= "password" name="password"  onkeyup='check();' required>


  <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label> 
  <input type="password" pattern= "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])(A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{12,}" placeholder="Repeat Password"  id= "confirm-password" name="confirm-password" onkeyup='check();' required>


  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeF200UAAAAAF1pKTeBDArjQ18LBh87bi4w1l1N"></div>
  <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </label>
  </form>


  <script>
  var check = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
      document.getElementById('confirm-password').value) {
      document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'green';
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'matching';
  } else {
      document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'red';
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'not matching';
  }
  }

  </script>




  <script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

My form action is action.php:

```
  if (isset($_POST['username']))
  {
  echo "IT IS SET!";
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $_POST['email'] = $email;
  $_POST['phone'] = $phone;
  $_POST['password'] = $password;
  $_POST['confirm-password'] = $confirmpassword;
  }
  var_dump($username);

  echo $password;
  echo $confirmpassword;
  echo $phone;
  echo $email;
  echo $username;
  var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

well you're overwriting all vars in your $POST before you actually var_dump() it. Try moving it to the top. I also reversed around your assignments, so you're not overwriting them vars.

```
var_dump($_POST); 
if (isset($_POST['username']))
  {
  echo "IT IS SET!";
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  //Reversed around your assignments
  $email = $_POST['email']; 
  $phone =$_POST['phone'];
  $password =$_POST['password'] ;
  $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirm-password'];
  }
var_dump($username);

echo $password;
echo $confirmpassword;
echo $phone;
echo $email;
echo $username;
```

Comment: Instead of reposting their code you should show them the *right* way to do it

Comment: I actually wanted them to notice the mistake... let them logic it out. I guess I could of just provided a comment above instead of doing it for them. :)